# die senkrecht darauf stehende z-Achse aber im Fall der Landfahrzeuge vom Erdmittelpunkt weg zeigt,

Tags: sentence-structure

> Wie dieser scheinbare Widerspruch zu erklären ist, zeigen die nebenstehenden Abbildungen: ENU- und NED-System gleichen sich darin, dass die xy-Ebene beider parallel zur Erdoberfläche verläuft, **die senkrecht darauf stehende z-Achse aber im Fall der Landfahrzeuge vom Erdmittelpunkt weg zeigt, bei Raum-, Luft- und Wasserfahrzeugen dagegen zum Erdmittelpunkt hin**

The verb seems to be "hinzeigen" in above bolded sentence however it seems to be not  listed in duden, I have difficulty to determine the object of the verb, also not understand why there is comma after verb "zeigt", overall I am fail to understand the structure. It will be helpful if you make the sentence simple

[Drehrichtung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drehrichtung)

Comment: DWDS: [hinzeigen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/hinzeigen).

Comment: There's no need for a specific verb "hinzeigen". What you have here is a free combination of *zeigen* with the circumposition *zu ... hin*.

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer. So far you asked ten questions on SE German. All of them were answered, but in no case you accepted an answer.

Comment: @RHa what do I need to do for that?

Comment: @ughitudhi See https://german.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we turn the bolded clause into a main clause, we get:

> Die senkrecht darauf stehende z-Achse zeigt aber im Fall der Landfahrzeuge vom Erdmittelpunkt weg, bei Raum-, Luft- und Wasserfahrzeugen dagegen zum Erdmittelpunkt hin.

There are two prepositional objects: *vom Erdmittelpunkt* and *zum Erdmittelpunkt*.

The reason for the comma is the usage of "dagegen", which creates an antagonism between the part before and the part after the comma.

A simpler example:

> Karl trinkt Bier, Franz dagegen Wein. (*Karl is drinking beer, whereas Franz is drinking wine.*)

Comment: Would be a good enhancement to point out that _zeigen weg (von)_ and _zeigen hin (zu)_ are separate words (adverbs) and not a form of _hinzeigen_ or _wegzeigen_.

Comment: In my view this can be interpreted both ways.

Comment: Hmm, could be. Well, at least I didn't find any self-contained verb _wegzeigen_ at DWDS.

Comment: So *hinzeigen* exists, but *wegzeigen* doesn't. A strange asymmetry. I admit that's a reason to interpret *hin* and *weg* as adverbs and not as a part of a separable verb.

Comment: That was my reasoning, yes. Though a _strange asymmetry_, I totally agree. It could also be a miss of DWDS, but such seem to be extremely rare.

Comment: @rha when you say "If we turn this clause into a main clause" then which clause it was before?

Comment: @ughitudhi That sub-clause you've bolded in your question of coarse.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ" dass" is ignored in the second time ?

Comment: "dass" introduces the subclause. If the subclause is converted into a main clause then the "dass" disappears.

Comment: @RHa I did not find verb valency as "zeigen zu or von" ?

Comment: @ughitudhi _"I did not find verb valency as "zeigen zu or von" ?"_ As I mentioned in my comment these are usage of proverbs in this case (and quite usual).

Comment: When you say sub-clause that means "(dass) die senkrecht darauf... "?

Comment: *dass* introduces an enumeration of three clauses, separated by commas.The bolded text contains the last two clauses.

Comment: @RHa Do I understand  last clause correctly? "dass  die senkrecht darauf stehende z-Achse bei Raum-, Luft- und Wasserfahrzeugen dagegen zum Erdmittelpunkt hin zeigt"

Comment: @ughitudhi Right.

Answer (score 2):

German has lots of compound words. To list all possible compound German words in a dictionary would almost be as excessive as listing all possible nominal groups. This just makes no sense, because in German you almost always can build new words by combining some other words. (There are rules and limitations, but if you count every compound word as a distinct word in German, German would have many millions of possible words.)

Depending on the context, some prefixes can be attached to almost every verb you can think of. The prefix *»hin-«* is one of them:

> - Karl und Anna tanzen auf einem Ball. Da entdecken sie einen gemeinsamen Freund am Rand der Tanzfläche. Karl sagt zu Anna: »Komm, lass uns zu Jürgen **hintanzen.**
> - Julia bereitet sich auf einen Kochwettbewerb vor. Marlene zweifelt an den Chancen von Julia. Darauf angesprochen entgegnet Julia: »Ich habe ja noch 4 Monate Zeit, da werde ich jeden Tag kochen und immer besser werden. I werde mich schon noch auf das geforderte Niveau **hinkochen.**

Here are even more examples for valid verbs with prefixes, that you might not find in any dictionary.

> - Im Kindergarten sitzen fast alle Kinder am Tisch und malen Bilder. Nur Anna hockt alleine in einer Ecke. Die Tante geht zu ihr und fragt sie: »Na, möchtest du nicht mit den anderen Kindern **mitmalen**?
> - »Bevor Sie die Figuren aus dem Blech ausschneiden, empfehle ich Ihnen, dass Sie die Kontouren **vorritzen**.«

Answer (score 2):

This sentence is not well thought-out.

> ENU- und NED-System gleichen sich darin, dass die xy-Ebene beider parallel zur Erdoberfläche verläuft, die senkrecht darauf stehende z-Achse aber im Fall der Landfahrzeuge vom Erdmittelpunkt weg zeigt, bei Raum-, Luft- und Wasserfahrzeugen dagegen zum Erdmittelpunkt hin.

The two systems **are similar** in one respect: the xy-plane is parallel to the surface of the earth. However, they **differ** with regard to the z-axis, which points either up (away from the earth's core) or down (towards the earth's core).

Therefore, having everything be subordinate to the verb *gleichen* is just wrong; another verb, such as *sich unterscheiden*, needs to be added.

> ENU- und NED-System **gleichen sich darin, dass** die xy-Ebene beider parallel zur Erdoberfläche verläuft, **sie unterscheiden sich aber darin, dass** die senkrecht darauf stehende z-Achse im Fall der Landfahrzeuge vom Erdmittelpunkt weg zeigt, **während sie (die z-Achse)** bei Raum-, Luft- und Wasserfahrzeugen dagegen zum Erdmittelpunkt hin **zeigt**.

Regarding the status of **zum Mittelpunkt hin, weg**. Although of course particle verbs such as *hinweisen*, *weglegen* exist, there are also instances where *hin, weg* clearly belong to the prepositional phrase.

> Dazu bedient man sich der Schwerkraft, die **zum Erdmittelpunkt hin** nach dem Fallgesetz zunimmt. [1](https://www.school-scout.de/vorschau/25359/arbeitsblaetter-zu-kartographischen-themen.pdf)
>
> Die Sammler sind **zur Erdoberfläche hin** wasserdurchlässig. [2](http://www.patent-de.com/20001109/DE19841301A1.html)
>
> Alle Dinge hätten einen natürlichen Drang **zum Erdmittelpunkt hin**. [3](https://www.xn--katholische-hrfunkarbeit-xoc.de/?id=1631)

The meaning is that of a **trajectory**. In the third example, the prepositional phrase modifies *Drang*; in the other two, they modify the verb.

For another example of a prepositional phrase being modified by an adverb, see [this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/58022/35111).

Answer (score 1):

You can find "hinzeigen" e.g. in [Woxikon](https://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/hinzeigen.php). However, the basic verb is "zeigen" and in your sentence it occurs in two extended forms as "wegzeigen" and "hinzeigen" which indicate *directions*.

**wegzeigen von**: to point away from

**hinzeigen zu**: to point towards

Examples can be found [here](https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsch-englisch/von+etwas+wegzeigen).

So we can write your sentence somewhat clearer:

> Die senkrecht darauf stehende z-Achse zeigt im Fall der Landfahrzeuge *vom Erdmittelpunkt weg*, sie zeigt bei Raum-, Luft- und Wasserfahrzeugen *zum Erdmittelpunkt hin*.